# Opening a path to only get time from the internet while the server is totaly offline

Tags: linux, nginx, time, server, ntp

//there is an update to the situation
I have a server "NginX" that is totally isolated from the internet and basically offline, the only thing that I want to get from the internet is that I want to get the exact time and date, so this means I should get that from an NTP server, which comes to our next problem, which is that my server it is configured in a way that it only supports White list filtering using IPs and not domain names, and the devices which I am using are connecting to **time.izatcloud.net** and **android.pool.ntp.org** to obtain time and only those two ones, I reached out to some technical contacts which probably won't answer and they are not open for contact...etc
If anyone has any solutions/propositions please feel free to propose them.

Comment: But didn't you also get IP addresses? I'm not sure why your time server admins need to respond to email. An internet search brought me to the NIST (a good provider for servers in the USA). Those addresses should remain stable. https://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi

Comment: Can you not open UDP port 123 for outgoing connections?

Comment: @tdelaney, I have devices that are already configured to use the domains I mentioned above so there is no possibility of changing them and using other sources. Android devices to be precise

Comment: @RichardSmith no it is not a practical way, the server is basically running an industrial solution, I need those two domains to be reachable by the devices, and only those two ones.

Comment: This might be better asked on serverfault.com. Its common to use GPS and an NTP server in your protected domain for off-internet time sync. How this works with your already-configured machines may be a problem. You could also potentially setup your own DNS server with a very thin configuration. Or, if your machines support it, give them preconfigured hosts files.

Comment: @tdelaney indeed, we did think about a DNS server that will resolve the needed IPs. I will contact them and try getting helpful information, thanks though

Comment: I don't know your exact situation but I would push hosts files out to our clusters that only held the targets they needed. The infrastructure was simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, Network engineers had to put configurations that allowed the firewall to filter the outgress requests based on the domain name which was not an available option at the beginning. We could not ping another time server because of the devices that we are using ping to these specific two domain names.
After a small recon about the two mentioned domain names we had to open the network using Nmap we found two other one: time.cloudflare.com and an EC2 Amazon domain ec2-34-217-74-63.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com.

after allowing these two domain names through a specific port the devices were able to pull the time and ping to those two servers.

*Thanks to those who participated, sorry fo the lack of information it was sort of a general solution that I would wanted to reach, I could not share further details.*